# Does VS Code support copying text in set range of lines?

Tags: visual-studio-code, copy, line, copy-paste, shortcut

Suppose that I have 1 000 000 lines of text in .txt file. I want to copy lines from 350 000 to 700 000. Is there any shortcut for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code v1.46 has a new [selection anchor](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_46#_accessibility) feature that helps you to select multiple lines easier.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, type `350000` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It would jump to line 350 000.
2. Place your cursor at the **very start** of line 350 000. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to set selection anchor. If this shortcut is not working, open command palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, search for 'Set Selection Anchor' and select that option.
3. After placing the selection anchor, you should see a thin vertical blue line at the very start of line 350 000
4. Jump to line 700 000 by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, then type `700000` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Place your cursor at **very end** of line 700 000. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to select from anchor to cursor.
6. Now, lines 350 000 to 700 000 should be selected. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy them.